# iOS development with Swift for enterprise applications

Tags: ios, swift

We are starting a new project in the company. This will be an enterprise application. But I would like to know the current status of iOS development using swift.
Can someone give details of their experience for following points:

1. Is Xcode 6.4 and above stable for swift programming ?
2. Will objective c work with swift without any huge effort ?
3. Are there enough communities and forums to ask for help ?
4. Does new versions of swift language and compiler breaks the existing implementations ?

Comment: At first I voted to close since this seemed subjective based on the question title. But all the specific questions are pretty objectively answerable, I think - maybe you should change the question title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is Xcode 6.4 and above stable for swift programming ?

No. Swift 2.0 requires Xcode 7, and Swift 1.2 is a dead-end, as the 2.0 version of the language is a (large) breaking change. In the same way, iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) both requires Xcode 7 for development.

> Will objective c work with swift without any huge effort ?

Yes. I'll recommend you watch the [Swift and Objective-C Interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=401) video from WWDC 2015.

> Are there enough communities and forums to ask for help ?

That's a amusing question to ask on the largest community in the world on Swift programming: Stack Overflow

> Does new versions of swift language and compiler breaks the existing implementations ?

Swift 2.0 broke Swift 1.2 implementations. Nobody can guarantee that Apple won't break Swift 2.0 with Swift 2.1, and Apple in general makes no promises of support for anything that isn't the absolute latest version of their software or platforms.

However Xcode 7 comes with functionality to update Swift 1.2 to Swift 2.0, and it mostly works for all code.

Overall, while Xcode 7 at the point of writing is in Beta, and therefore have certain issues, once it's out of Beta, it'll be fully endorsed by Apple as the development environment for all applications on their platform, and as such, also Enterprise applications.

Writing Swift 2.0 in my professional work, my personal opinion is that it's indeed ready for Enterprise applications -- maybe even more than Objective-C ever were.

Answer (score -1):

1. Absolutely.
2. Mostly. It gets kinda dicey when you try to alternate languages in a class hierarchy because you can wind up with a circular dependency. For example, if you have base class `A` written in Obj-C, with a subclass `B` written in Swift, you can't easily have a subclass `C` of `B` written in Obj-C because A needs to be added to the `<projectName>-Bridging-Header.h` file so that Swift can see it, and  `C`'s header file needs to include the `<projectName>-Swift.h` generated header file, and that a circular dependency.
3. Yes.
4. So far, many of them have, especially the moves to Swift 1.1 and 1.2.

Comment: XCode 6.4 will not work with Swift 2.0 and iOS 9

Answer (score -1):

> Is Xcode 6.4 and above stable for swift programming ?

You are going to want to wait until XCode 7 GM comes out just before iOS 9 is released. XCode 6.4 won't be able to build for iOS 9.

> Will objective c work with swift without any huge effort ?

[Yes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

> Are there enough communities and forums to ask for help ?

You're on one of the better communities right now! :]

> Does new versions of swift language and compiler breaks the existing
>       implementations ?

Sometimes. Over the course of Swift 1.0 - 1.2, Swift updates have been negligible for development. Swift 2.0 added many new language features, and broke a moderate amount of code in on of our larger projects. With Swift 2.0 and the language stabilizing as a whole, the disruption you should experience should be minimal.